# What is the difference between notwendig and erforderlich?

Tags: colloquial, comparison

In the song *Vor Gericht* by Alligatoah is this lyric:

"Gewalt ist zum Zerstören nicht erforderlich" (Violence is not necessary to cause destruction"

My two questions about this sentence relate to the use of *erforderlich* vs. *notwendig*:

- Are they completely interchangeable here (austauchen)?  If not why?
- Which is more common in everyday German conversation?  I ask this one because some German bands sometimes use exotic or archaic word forms to make an interesting point or for rhyming purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Literally, *erforderlich* translates to *required*, and *notwendig* translates to *necessary*.

## Interchangeability

In most cases, they are fully interchangeable.

*erforderlich* might bear some associations, that the object is "required by someone", or rather the requirement is "imposed by someone", while *notwendig* could imply a more objective necessity. This is due to the fact, that the stem of *erforderlich* is the stem of the verb *fordern* which translates to *demand*, *ask for*, *call for*, *require*, hence *erforderlich* could ring a bell of a social interaction. Thus, using *erforderlich* might frame the message in a more personal way.

But the nuance is very small, and it is not even a necessary association - the verb *erfordern* means *to necessitate*, *to require*, *to need*, which is closer to an objective frame, than the mere stem *fordern*. You can easily say sentences like

> Die Situation erforderte schnelles Handeln (*The situation needed quick action*.)

where there is no person involved requiring anything, but *erfordern* expresses some rather objective necessity.

Use and interchangeability of *erforderlich* and *notwendig* are very analogous to  their English translations, I'd say.

## Style and Tone

From my experience I would say that *notwendig*, or even *nötig* is more common and more colloquial, and *erforderlich* is more bureaucratic and formal.